# A way to get the value of N choose R for all values of R?

Tags: combinations

Is there a formula or perhaps an automatic calculator online (or a method in excel) by which I can calculate the total number of combinations one can pick of all sizes from a set of n items?

i.e. if n = 4, I would like the quantity of values from r=1 to r=4 (which works out to 15, but I need a formula or computational method to do it automatically for any value of n.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni$?  That's just $2^n$.  (if you want the sum to start at $i=1$ it's $2^n-1$, as in $2^4-1=15$).  This follows from the binomial theorem (or from counting the subsets of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$)

Comment: How did I not think of that....so elegant and straightforward. Put it into an answer if you wish so I can mark as best.